# Subscript out of bounds while building RF

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to build a classifier based upon a random forest in r.

The code to reproduce this:

```
    library(quantmod)
    library(randomForest)

    getSymbols('^GSPC', from="2002-01-01") 
    GSPC <- GSPC[,1:5] # remove adjusted close
    GSPC$wkret <- lag(GSPC$GSPC.Close,-5)/GSPC$GSPC.Close # build weekly future return
    GSPC$wkret <- GSPC$wkret * 100 -100 # build index

    cutoff <- floor(dim(GSPC)[1]/4) # select the row at 25%
    cutoffbreak <- sort(abs(as.data.frame(GSPC$wkret)[,1]),decreasing=T)[cutoff] # get the top 25% return in absolute terms
    y <- cut(GSPC$wkret, breaks=c('-100',-cutoffbreak,cutoffbreak ,'100'),labels=c('down','','up')) # build factors 
    randomForest(GSPC[1:100],y[1:100]) # select first 100 to exclude NA's, dimension problems.
```

This works:

```
y[1:100]
[1]                                                                                      down      down down
 [22]                up   up        down      down                          up   up   up   up 
=== zip ===

> is.factor(y)
[1] TRUE

> x[1:100]
              open    high     low   close     volume
2002-01-02 1148.08 1154.67 1136.23 1154.67 1171000000
2002-01-03 1154.67 1165.27 1154.01 1165.27 1398900000
2002-01-04 1165.27 1176.55 1163.42 1172.51 1513000000
2002-01-07 1172.51 1176.97 1163.55 1164.89 1308300000
=== zip ===

> class(x)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

This works (but makes no sense of course):

```
lm(y[1:100] ~ .,data=x[1:100])
```

but building a randomforest gives:

```
> rf <- randomForest(y[1:100] ~ .,data=x[1:100])
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : subscript out of bounds

> traceback()
4: randomForest.default(m, y, ...)
3: randomForest(m, y, ...)
2: randomForest.formula(y[1:100] ~ ., data = x[1:100])
1: randomForest(y[1:100] ~ ., data = x[1:100])
```

googling around says this is a dimensions problem, but can't figure out why/how.

r version:

> R.version
>                  _
>           platform       i686-pc-linux-gnu
>           arch           i686
>           os             linux-gnu
>           system         i686, linux-gnu
>           status
>           major          2
>           minor          15.1
>           year           2012
>           month          06
>           day            22
>           svn rev        59600
>           language       R
>           version.string R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
>           nickname       Roasted Marshmallows

library versions:

```
    randomForest version: "2.15.1"
    quantmod version: "2.15.1"
```

Comment: That's a pretty weird way of using randomForest's formula interface. Try just passing `x` and `y` parameters directly.

Comment: x[1:100] is not a matrix, but a vector. This cannot work.

Comment: @January Yeah; not sure if RF will coerce to matrix or not if they switch to `y = y[1:100],x = x[1:100]` or not.

Comment: Although others may be able to tell what you're working with, it is anything but reproducible for me.  Please put `dput` to use (see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000).  Why are you subsetting the 1st 100 rows of what appears to be a 4 row object?

Comment: Ugh. Is that your attempt at reproducibility? `> GSPC$[lagged column on close]
Error: unexpected '[' in "GSPC$["`

Comment: @Gsee I will update my post with a github gist. Didn't know dput, and thought i was overlooking something obvious.
To answer your second question: to prove/troubleshoot there can't be a dimensions problem (as far as i see).

Comment: Ok, but seems a bit overkill.  Do you know about `quantmod::getSymbols`?

Comment: @Gsee yes, that's where I built x from. (i have updated the starting post, and no, the first code was for logic, not reproducability)

Comment: Why can't you just show us the code you used to build the objects?  The link you gave has syntax errors in it.

Comment: @Gsee i have updated the post with full code.

Answer (score 2):

There was something wrong when i created y.
The code runs fine when i add this:

```
    y <- as.factor(as.numeric(y))
```

I have no idea what was wrong with my y value, but i recognize that this was only reproducable when i provided the full code.

```
    > randomForest(na.omit(GSPC),y[1:2713])
    Error in randomForest.default(na.omit(GSPC), y[1:2713]) : 
      subscript out of bounds
    > y <- as.factor(as.numeric(y))
    > randomForest(na.omit(GSPC),y[1:2713])

    Call:
     randomForest(x = na.omit(GSPC), y = y[1:2713]) 
                   Type of random forest: classification
                         Number of trees: 500
    No. of variables tried at each split: 2

            OOB estimate of  error rate: 0.07%
    Confusion matrix:
        1    2   3 class.error
    1 348    1   0 0.002865330
    2   0 2034   0 0.000000000
    3   0    1 329 0.003030303
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling randomForest with a formula and data parameter is pretty usual, however `x[1:100]` is not a matrix, but a vector. I think you mean `x[1:100,]`.

Furthermore, the parameter to data should be a data frame, not a matrix. I assume that x is a matrix (rather than a data frame), because `x[1:100]` would otherwise return the following error message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, 100) : undefined columns selected
```

Alternatively, as suggested by comments, you can also run

```
randomForest( x[ 1:100, ], y[ 1:100 ] )
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure you're technically correct about `x[1:100]` being a vector. The OP implied that `x` is an **xts** object, which are a bit different. Create an `xts` object and play around with `is.vector` and `is.matrix`. I think you may be surprised.

Comment: damn! I have overlooked that.

Comment: Indeed, I just verified for myself that I can pass an `xts` object directly to the randomForest `x` argument without first coercing it to a matrix.

Comment: An xts object _is_ a matrix (with an index attribute)

Comment: @January, thanks, but i should have mentioned this removal of , was done as part of the troubleshooting, after verifying it gave the same (optical) result.
Your code gives the same error as before.

Comment: Try converting your time series to a regular data frame, and run that.

Comment: @January 
        randomForest(as.data.frame(GSPC[1:100,]),y[1:100])

has the same issue